# derivatives of double summation equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

[image: f(x)]

I want to get the derivative of this function wrt xi.(dy/dxi)

I tried to work this out and I got (2 * f(x) * (Qi@x + Qii * xi + Qji * xj)).

Q is an nxn covariance matrix and x are the weights of a portfolio(nx1).

@ is matrix multiplication.

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\S{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}
$For typing convenience, define the all-ones vector $\o$,
the all-ones matrix $J$, and the variables
$$\eqalign{
w &= Qx &\qiq dw &= Q\,dx \\
W &= \Diag w  \\
X &= \Diag x  \\
C &= I - \tfrac 1nJ &&\quad\big\{{\rm Centering\;Matrix}\big\} \\
p &= x\odot w &\qiq dp&=w\odot dx + x\odot dw \\
&&&= W\,dx  + X\,dw \\
&&&= \LR{W+XQ}dx \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Let's also introduce the Frobenius product as a convenient
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \S A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms
in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different
but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
\\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to rewrite the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \S\LR{p_i-p_j}^2 \\
 &= \S\LR{p_i^2 - 2p_ip_j + p_j^2} \\
 &= \S\LR{p_i^2\o_j - 2p_ip_j + \o_ip_j^2} \\
 &= n\LR{\sum_{i=1}^np_i^2} - 2\LR{\S p_ip_j} + n\LR{\sum_{j=1}^np_j^2} \\
 &= 2n\LR{I:pp^T} - 2\LR{J:pp^T} \\
\phi &= 2n{C:pp^T} \\
}$$
and calculate its gradient vector
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= 2nC:\LR{dp\,p^T + p\,dp^T}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \\
 &= 4nC:\LR{dp\,p^T} \\
 &= 4nCp:{dp} \\
 &= 4nCp:\LR{W+XQ}dx \\
 &= 4n\LR{W+Q^TX}Cp:dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= 4n\LR{W+Q^TX}Cp \\
}$$
To extract the $k^{th}$ component, multiply by the
Euclidean basis vector $e_k$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{x_k} &= \gradLR{\phi}{x}^Te_k \\
 &= 4n\;p^TC\LR{W+XQ}e_k \\
 &= 4n\,\BR{\LR{p^TCe_k}w_k + \LR{p^TCXQe_k}} \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I greatly appreciate it.  I still have some questions about the dimensions of the matrices in your final solution.

Comment: So, W and Q'X should all be nxn matrices right? But how about Cp?  How can I calculate C? I assume that I is a column vector nx1 and J is a nxn matix.

Comment: The [Centering Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix) is a fairly well-known concept in statistics.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.